# Массив обьектов. Шаблоны классов С++

Tags: c++, классы, stl, шаблоны-с++

Как создать массив обьектов из шаблонных классов?
[Вот моя попытка](https://repl.it/OGCx).

> > Ошибка: ain.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:46:28: error: no matching function for call to 'Mnozhina::Mnozhina(int&)'
> >     Mnozhina  myStack(n);
> >                                 ^ main.cpp:13:5: note: candidate: Mnozhina::Mnozhina() [with T = int]
> >          Mnozhina()
> >          ^~~~~~~~ main.cpp:13:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided main.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: constexpr
> >     Mnozhina::Mnozhina(const Mnozhina&)  class Mnozhina
> >            ^~~~~~~~ main.cpp:7:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Mnozhina&'

`Mnozhina <int > myStack(n);`
Я понимаю что такое  `<int >` если мы используем `template <typename T>`
Но как подобное будет выглядеть когда мы запишем `template <class T>`

И где в моем коде ошибки и какие. Так как в STL, я пока полный нуб.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Mnozhina
{
private:
  int n;
  int * arr=new int [n];
public:
    Mnozhina()
    {
      n=10;
    }

    ~Mnozhina();
    void set_Mnozhina()
    {
      //cout<<"numbers of elements is here: ";
      //cin>>n;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        arr[i]=2*i;  // parni numbers 
      }
    }
    void get_Mnozshina()
    { 
      cout<<"array is here =) :";
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
      }
    }


};

int main () 
{  
  int n;

  cout<<"numbers of elements is here: ";
  cin>>n;
  Mnozhina <int > myStack(n);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: В конструкции `template<typename T>` ключевые слова `typename` и `class` полностью взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка - отсутствие конструктора, который бы получал `int` в качестве аргумента.

Далее, у вас объявлен деструктор, но не реализован.

Инициализировать `arr` все же лучше в конструкторе.

Раз вы работаете с динамической памятью, нужно или написать копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания, или их запретить.

В деструкторе надо удалять выделенную память.

Т.е. для начала - что-то вроде

```
template <class T>
    class Mnozhina
{
private:
    int n;
    int * arr;
public:
    Mnozhina(int n = 10):n(n),arr(new int[n])
    {
        set_Mnozhina();
    }
    ~Mnozhina() { delete[] arr; }

    Mnozhina(const Mnozhina&) = delete;
    Mnozhina& operator=(const Mnozhina&) = delete;


    void set_Mnozhina()
    {
        //cout<<"numbers of elements is here: ";
        //cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=2*i;  // parni numbers
        }
    }
    void get_Mnozshina()
    {
        cout<<"array is here =) :";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    }


};

int main ()
{
    int n;

    cout<<"numbers of elements is here: ";
    cin>>n;
    Mnozhina<int> myStack(n);

    myStack.get_Mnozshina();

    return 0;
}
```